# type coercion error handling in tapestry 5

Tags: error-handling, tapestry, type-coercion

sometimes user enters text that cannot be coerced properly. e.g. string -> money. '123 USD' can be coerced properly but '123 ZZZ' or 'dwerss' can't. one of the examples can be checked by regexp on client side but other can not. how should i handle those errors and display proper message to the user?
is it described in any tutorial? any link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [Translator](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/Translator.html) as described by [jumpstart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/input/creatingtranslators1) and the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/CreatingCustomTranslators).

You can throw a ValidationException in the parseClient implementation if the input is entirely unusable.